# How to make InnerHTML to work as innerText?

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I am currently working on a google chrome extension and I want to highlight the searched word.

I am highlighting by finding the match in innerHTML and adding "mark" tag around it. The problem is that when I do this if the searched word was used as a function name or tag name inside the HTML code also gets highlighted.

I want the innerHTML to work as innerText so that I could add  tag around the matched word and the matched word won't be any elements of HTML code.

Can someone help me out in figuring this problem out, please?

I have this code so far:

```js
var match = new RegExp(request + "(?![^<>]*>)", "gi");
document.documentElement.innerHTML = document.documentElement.innerHTML.replace(match, function (match) {
  return ("<mark style='background-color: #FFFF99;'>" + match + "</mark>");
});
```

Comment: What you tried so far? Add code samples.

Comment: It's a tricky problem. This looks like it might be helpful: https://www.npmjs.com/package/rangy

Comment: @MadanSapkota `var match= new RegExp(request+"(?![^<>]*>)","gi");
    document.documentElement.innerHTML=document.documentElement.innerHTML.replace(match,function (match) {
        return ("<mark style='background-color: #FFFF99;'>"+match+"</mark>");
    });` I used regexp to ignore the matched words that are inside <> tags and highlighted the rest of the matched words